# Migration of cut vs. non-cut plasmid on gel

Tags: molecular-biology, plasmids, gel-electrophoresis, minipreps

As you might know there are 3 common forms of a plasmid:

- **ccc-form (CCC)**, being supercoiled.
- **oc-form (OC)**, being nicked and therefore relaxed.
- **linearized form (L)**, being cut on both strands and linear.

In theory the fastest migration should be the CCC, then L and the slowest is the OC-form.
Source: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0147619X81900123

So I have a plasmid with 7631 bp from a Midiprep. I cut this plasmid with NotI and put both versions on a gel, to check for the quality of the Midiprep.
I expected my plasmid to have the CCC form and therefore be faster (lower) than the cut L-form.
I ran the gel and the result is the opposite. My plasmid runs slower (higher) than the cut version.
Why is that? Do I have a misunderstanding somewhere? Is my plasmid ok?

[image]

For clarification: NotI- means that the plasmid is not cut. NotI+ means that the plasmid is cut (and therefore linear).

Comment: What organism are you propagating your plasmids in? What kind of gel / buffer are you using?

Comment: E. Coli (DH5-alpha). 
This is a 1% agarose gel with 1x TAE.
Digest was done with NEB enzymes and CutSmart-Buffer according to protocol. Non-cut plasmid was treated the same, but without enzyme.

Comment: What kind of plasmid prep are you using? I remember having rarely seen the ccc form. If all three where present, it was usually the weakest band.

Comment: What do you mean with plasmid "pred"? The kit is from Qiagen. The plasmid itself is a vector for lentiviral transduction. I'm just confused because only the oc-form would be slower than linear. But I don't believe that all my plasmid is nicked.

Comment: @FelixH. Pred -> prep. If you are new at this game, you probably won't see much supercoiled, mostly circular or nicked circular. Supercoiled can also run in quite a few positions depending on the state and if you overloaded or not.  I'm assuming that the NotI+ is running at the correct size (only 1 cut site)? If so, don't worry about how the uncut is running too much. That looks like 1kb plus ladder; if so, size is right.

Comment: It should have been "prep", a simple typo. Otherwise I agree with @bob1

Comment: @bob1 Thank you for the reply! I'm not particularly new at these things, but once in a while I try to ask myself questions that are considered "basic" or "easy" but most (even advanced) scientists around me do not seem to have an explanation for. A good midiprep should be mostly supercoiled. bitesizebio.com/13524/… pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22693686 
It also does not seem to be overloaded, since its roughly 200 ng/µL (diluted midi).
The cut is the correct size and yes NotI cuts one time in my plasmid.
The ladder is 1kb+.

Comment: Just for clarification, I know that the midiprep is probably fine, but I experience so often that people around me tell me "that's just the way it is", instead of trying to find proper explanations. I'm just curious why my results do not fit with the standard theory/papers of plasmid migration.

Comment: @FelixH. always good to challenge the paradigm! I agree your midiprep looks good.  In my experience, supercoiled can run in a number of positions relative to cut; I can't recall exactly the reasons I was taught many years ago, but I think residual protein contamination, entangling of the ccc form with others, and overloading/underloading all play a role.

Comment: @bob1 Thanks for your reply. Entangling sounds like a reasonable explanation - I think I have even read that somewhere recently, when I was trying to find an answer.